# Tomcat : Marking servlet hbws as unavailable

Tags: tomcat

I am getting

```
SEVERE: Servlet /hbws threw load() exception
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:
The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved
    The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved
    The import org.apache cannot be resolved
```

My `servlet-api.jar` is available in `$CATALINE_HOME/lib`. But why still i an getting this error.

I am getting this when i that my server(Tomcat 6.0.32).

Comment: How are you compiling the servlet code? Using `javac` or just by saving/running in an IDE like Eclipse/Netbeans?

Comment: I have build code using Ant. There is no compilation error in code. But when i deployed war file into Tomcat. I will getting this exception.

Comment: Please note that, getting same error for some other jar.. which i have not mention here. Even i dont want to add that jar to WEB_INF\lib. 
So do will i add those jar to CLASSPATH so that tomcat(6.0.32) will refer it. I have tried all option. But i am facing same issue.